# Finding matching male / female connectors

Tags: connector

I've been having trouble finding pairs of connectors. I need a set up exactly like https://www.artekit.eu/products/prototyping/wires/jst-ph-4-pin-cable-with-male-female-connector/

[image]

However, I need to buy the male and female parts separately. So, I'm looking at male connectors like https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/S4B-ZR-LF-SN/455-1671-ND/926578

[image]

But then how, having just the male connector, do I go about finding a female connector which I know will fit into the male connector?

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to verify my connectors will fit correctly. I would think the male and females would be linked in some manner that I'm missing?

Comment: You want 2mm or 1.5mm?

Comment: Either really, it's for I2C lines. It's just, I need a connection that snaps in place, and if the male and female don't snap in the same way I don't think they'll fit together.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is on the digikey page linked within the question.

Comment: Don't be so quick. This might seem obvious to you, but I looked for a long time without realizing where to find the answer. Transistor's answer helped me quite a bit and could help others in the future.

Comment: "But then how, having just the male connector, do I go about finding a female connector which I know will fit into the male connector?" - well, after clicking on that **Digikey link you already have**, you scroll down to the bottom and look at the section labeled "**Mating Products**" ...

Answer (score 2):

On the web catalogue page you linked is a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the [ZH series](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eZH.pdf) connectors. This will contain tables of all the compatible connectors in the range.

[image]

*Figure 1. Top and side-entry versions with through-hole or SMT options.*

Choose the orientation you require (top / side entry, etc.) and the number of ways and you will find your part numbers.

Then return to Digikey and search for the ZH part numbers.